# How does Verilog treat multiple if blocks inside always_ff

Tags: verilog

If I have two `if` statements inside an `always_ff` block, such as:

```
always_ff @(posedge clk) begin
    if (x >= 5) begin
        // do something
    end
    if (x <= 7) begin
        // do something
    end
end
```

If x=6, which means both conditions are satisfied, will both `if` blocks get executed, or only the first one?

Comment: Both get "executed". Remember, this is HDL, so both get "activated" in parallel. If they both assign to the same signal(s), the last assignment in the block will prevail.

Answer (score 1):

All code within a `begin`/`end` block gets *executed* consecutively. When the first `if` condition is *true*, the statements inside the next `begin`/`end` block get executed consecutively. Then when the the second `if` condition is *true*, the statements inside the next `begin`/`end` block get executed consecutively.

When both conditions are true, you will have two sets of statement blocks executing consecutively. If your intent is to have only one block execute, then you should be using the `else` clause.

Comment: With the clarification that the signals **as seen from outside the block** that are given new values inside the various `if` statements will not change more than once in a simulation cycle. The notion of consecutive execution applies only inside the `always` block.

Answer (score 0):

There are 2 possible conditions here: 1) We are allocating values to the same register in both if conditions; 2) We are allocating values to different registers in the two if conditions.

1. If we are dealing with condition #1, i.e., allocating values to the
   same register (lets say "z") then: The second if condition would run as follows: The final value of "z" would be "2" after the clk posedge..

   ```
   if (x >= 5) begin
     z <= 1;
   end
   if (x <= 7) begin
     z <= 2;
   end
   ```
2. If we dealing with condition #2, i.e., allocating values to different registers in the two if conditions, then both if conditions would run as follows: We would have values for y = 1 and z = 2 after the clk posedge.

   ```
   if (x >= 5) begin
      y <= 1;
   end
   if (x <= 7) begin
      z <= 2;
   end
   ```

The rules for all Verilog behavior are set in the IEEE Std 1800-2017. Section 9.3.1 Sequential blocks, states:

> A sequential block shall have the following characteristics:
> — Statements shall be executed in sequence, one after another.

In this context, a sequential block is defined by the begin/end keywords.

Also, section 10.4.2 Nonblocking procedural assignments:

> The order of the execution of distinct nonblocking assignments to a given variable shall be preserved.

Comment: The first one will *also* run, though. You don't say that it won't, but it's unclear.

Comment: @Hearth yes you are right if we are allocating values to different register. Thanks for making that clear, I'll edit my answer.